# How to merge duplicate rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C'],'name':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

As of now the output for above code is:

```
id  name
 A     1
 A     2
 A     3
 B     4
 B     5
 B     6
 C     7
```

But I am expeting its output like:

```
id    name
A     1,2,3
B     4,5,6
C     7
```

I ain't sure how to do it, I have tried several other codes but didn't work for me. Please help in solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a comma separated list of values, you can aggregate using `join`, noting that you have to convert the values to strings first:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
print(df2.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
id  name
 A 1,2,3
 B 4,5,6
 C     7
```

If you just want a list of values, aggregate using `list`:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(list)
print(df2.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
id      name
 A [1, 2, 3]
 B [4, 5, 6]
 C       [7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby()`, `apply()` and `reset_index()`:

```
df = df.groupby("id")['name'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
  id       name
0  A  [1, 2, 3]
1  B  [4, 5, 6]
2  C        [7]
```

Additionally, if you want the `name` column to be a `string` instead of a `list`, you can do the following:

```
df = df.groupby("id")['name'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: ",".join(str(i) for i in x)).reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
  id   name
0  A  1,2,3
1  B  4,5,6
2  C      7
```